# A Cournot question

Tags: microeconomics

I am confused that If the marginal costs of the two firms are different, is it still a Cournot model?
I saw many examples that  give a fixed marginal cost of the products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can have different marginal costs in a Cournot model. Here is a simple example:

Two firms with marginal costs of $c_1$ and $c_2$ competing in quantities where inverse demand is $p=A-b(q_1+q_2)$. Firms are maximizing:
$$\max_{q_i} \; (A-b(q_1 + q_2))q_i - c_i q_i$$
Taking a derivative and solving you can find unique quantities, e.g.
$$q_1 = \frac{A+2b(c_1 -A) - c_2}{4b^2 -1}$$

You mention that marginal costs are often given as "fixed". This is often done for simplicity. It can be challenging to solve a Cournot model with increasing/decreasing returns and an equilibrium may not exist.

Comment: May I ask do you use some apps to write formulas?

Comment: No, you can find more information about how to write math (LaTeX) on Stack Exchange here: https://economics.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex